# Tailscale speed on LAN much slower than the LAN connection

Tags: tailscale

I asked this on Stackoverflow, and I was directed to ask here instead:
I am using Tailscale to connect a couple of my computers, and I noticed that the speed is very slow when I measured with iPerf, even between computers on the same LAN.
I was actually comparing the speed between a Hyper-V host and a VM running on that host, and when specifying the LAN IP address, I got speeds of 2.5 Gbits/sec average, and when testing the Tailscale IP address of the same 2 computers, I got speeds of 30 Mbits/sec average. Is Tailscale limiting the speed or how could I improve the speed through the Tailscale network?
Thank you.

Comment: I get 400mbits through tailscale locally vs 930 direct (gigabit lan)

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Tailscale may fall back to using external relays.

Comment: Try `tailscale ping {target tailscale IP}` and see if it uses one of the DERP relays or connects directly.